# How to redirect url with forward slash in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect my url:

`www.site.com/dashboard/invest-package.php?packageID=1`

to

`www.site.com/dashboard/invest-package/1`

Actually I solved this problem with `-`

`<a href="invest-package-'.$row['packageID'].'">Invest</a>`

```
RewriteRule ^invest-package-(.*)$ invest-package.php?packageID=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I wanted to make with "/" don't like using "-". Solutions I found on the internet didn't work. I keep getting 404 not found error.

**Here is my link to invest-package.php**

```
<a href="invest-package/'.$row['packageID'].'">Invest</a>
```

**and .htaccess file:**

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /dashboard/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]

RewriteRule ^invest-package/(.*)$ invest-package.php?packageID=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this code:

```sh
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dashboard/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^invest-package/([\w-]+)/?$ invest-package.php?packageID=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

It is important to turn off `MultiViews` i.e. the content negotiation service of Apache.

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.php` without any `GET` parameters.